# Django: Add number of results

Tags: django, view

I'm displaying the number of search results, however, i do more than one search.
So to display the number of results i'd have to add them up.
So i've tried this:

```
<p>Found {{ products|length + categories|length + companies|length }} results.</p>
```

But i get an error. 
How do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this in your view when you are creating your context dictionary:

```
'result_count': len(products) + len(categories) + len(companies)
```

Then, in your template, just use:

```
<p>Found {{ result_count }} results.</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

Django templates do not support arithmetic operators. However you can use the [add](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter. I think you need something like this:

```
<p>Found {{ products|length|add:categories|length|add:companies|length }} results.</p>
```

Alternatively you should calculate the total in the view and pass it pre-calculated to the template.

EDIT: Further to the comments, this version should work:

```
{% with categories|length as catlen %}
{% with companies|length as complen %}   
<p>Found {{ products|length|add:catlen|add:complen }} results.</p>
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

However, this feels very hacky and it would be preferable to calculate the figure in the view.

Comment: When I try `blah|length|add:blarg|length` I get TemplateSyntaxError "int() arg must be a string or a number".

Comment: Your suggestion is bringing up an error:
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QuerySet'

Comment: I have made it work (see edited answer), but you'd be better off calculating it in the view.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to point that Van Gale's answer is not optimal.
From [the QuerySet API documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/), you should use **query.count()** rather than **len(query)**

> A count() call performs a SELECT COUNT(*) behind the scenes, so you
>   should always use count() rather than loading all of the record into
>   Python objects and calling len() on the result (unless you need to
>   load the objects into memory anyway, in which case len() will be
>   faster).

So the answer should be:
In the view:

`'result_count': products.count() + categories.count() + companies.count()`

The template remains unchanged